# What is "Could not find com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0" in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>   Could not find com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0.
>        Required by:
>            project :app > com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0

Answer (score 2):

For using Twitter authentication you need to add following:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#identity-provider-configuration